# absolutely positioned div's content not hiding when width of div is changed

Tags: width, css-position, absolute

I have a sidebar div which is positioned absolutely. When i click the hamburger icon in mobile view, I am changing the width of that div to 0. That works perfectly but the menu items inside it are still visible. shouldn't they be hidden because the container div's width is 0?

Comment: Use `overflow : hidden`

Comment: Post the code please